# How to use StringArrays in a Custom ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android

I'm trying use a StringArray to display items in a ListView with a custom Adapter.

But it does not work.

```
package ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Acts;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.AbsSavedState;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.text.Format;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;

import ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Core.adapter.DrawerCustomListAdapter;
import ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Core.app.AppController;
import ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R;

import static ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R.id.content_frame;
import static ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R.id.toolbar;

public class HomeAct extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActionBar homeActionbar;
    String[] draweritems;
    List<String> drawerItems;
    int homeDrawerMenuItemsNumber=1;
    DrawerCustomListAdapter drawerCustomListAdapter;
    DrawerLayout homeDLayout;
    ListView homeDrawerListView;
    ImageView mainToolbarMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Localize...
        if (!Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fa")){
            String languageToLoad  = "fa";
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            this.setContentView(R.layout.act_about);
            setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.act_home);
        homeDLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        homeDrawerListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv);

        //Set Custom ToolBar...
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        homeActionbar=getSupportActionBar();
        final LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.toolbar, null);
        homeActionbar.setCustomView(v);
        homeActionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        //Set Custom ToolBar Objects...
        //MainToolBar Menu Image Object...
        mainToolbarMenu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_menu);
        mainToolbarMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (homeDLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
                    homeDLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                else homeDLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        //Set Custom Home Navigation Drawer...
        draweritems= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_titles);
        drawerItems=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(draweritems));
        drawerCustomListAdapter=new DrawerCustomListAdapter(this,draweritems);
        homeDrawerListView.setAdapter(drawerCustomListAdapter);
       // homeDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        //        this,R.layout.drawer_list_row,homeDrawerMenuItems));


       // homeDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        //        this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,homeDrawerMenuItems));

        homeDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_titles)[position];
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"برروی "+selectedItem+"کلیک شد!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

---

```
package ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Core.adapter;


import android.content.Context;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R;

public class DrawerCustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public Context context;
    public List<String> drawerItems;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public void drawerCustomListViewItemRow(
            Context context,List<String> drawerItems
    ){
        this.context=context;
        this.drawerItems=drawerItems;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return drawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return drawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_row, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_title);
        title.setText(drawerItems.get(position));
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_left);
        return vi;
    }

    /*

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_title); // title
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_icon); // thumb image

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(R.string.app_name);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_account_circle);
        return vi;
    }
    */
}
```

My Android Studio says that the problem is in HomeAct, where I typed: `(this,draweritems);`

Comment: please post the full error

Comment: `DrawerCustomListAdapter` does not have a constructor.

Comment: constructor?what and where i have to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added `void` here, therefore creating a method, not a constructor. Constructors have no return type.

Remove it

```
public **void** drawerCustomListViewItemRow(
        Context context,List<String> drawerItems
){
    this.context=context;
    this.drawerItems=drawerItems;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Also capitalize the D for your class name from `drawerCustomListViewItemRow` to instead `DrawerCustomListAdapter`

And use the List of `drawerItems`, not the array `draweritems` when you create the adapter. Probably best to only store one or the other, not both anyway.

Comment: perfect!it was realy helpfull.thanks alot

Comment: my eyes have problem with light.so my windows 10 OS theme is dark.and when it is dark ,many CSS styles be hide for me and i cannot see them!so can you tell me where is that in screen?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a constructor to your adapter class

change you'r drawerCustomListViewItemRow method name to this:

```
public DrawerCustomListAdapter(Context context, List<string> drawerItems)
```

and one more thing is that you have to either change `String[] draweritems;` in HomeAct to `List<string> draweritems;` or change the adapter List to string arary

Comment: incompatible types. found: java.lang.string[],required java.util.list<java.lang.string> ...........And these lines be red :  draweritems= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_titles);
        drawerItems=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(draweritems));
        DrawerCustomListAdapter=new DrawerCustomListAdapter(this,draweritems);

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Please check the difference. Your **DrawerCustomListAdapter** constructor was not ok.

> package ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Acts;
>
> import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.content.pm.ActivityInfo; import
>   android.content.res.Configuration; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton; import
>   android.support.design.widget.Snackbar; import
>   android.support.v4.view.AbsSavedState; import
>   android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat; import
>   android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat;
>   import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout; import
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; import android.view.Gravity; import
>   android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import
>   android.widget.AdapterView; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import
>   android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.ListView; import
>   android.widget.Toast;
>
> import java.lang.reflect.Field; import
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler; import java.text.Format; import
>   java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Arrays; import
>   java.util.Comparator; import java.util.List; import java.util.Locale;
>
> import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
>
> import ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Core.adapter.DrawerCustomListAdapter;
>   import ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Core.app.AppController; import
>   ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R;
>
> import static ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R.id.content_frame; import
>   static ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R.id.toolbar;
>
> public class HomeAct extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> ActionBar homeActionbar;
> String[] draweritems;
> List<String> drawerItems;
> int homeDrawerMenuItemsNumber = 1;
> DrawerCustomListAdapter drawerCustomListAdapter;
> DrawerLayout homeDLayout;
> ListView homeDrawerListView;
> ImageView mainToolbarMenu;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     //Localize...
>     if (!Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fa")) {
>         String languageToLoad = "fa";
>         Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
>         Locale.setDefault(locale);
>         Configuration config = new Configuration();
>         config.locale = locale;
>         getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
>                 getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
>         this.setContentView(R.layout.act_about);
>         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
>
>     }
>     setContentView(R.layout.act_home);
>     homeDLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>     homeDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv);
>
>     //Set Custom ToolBar...
>     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
>     homeActionbar = getSupportActionBar();
>     final LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
>             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>     View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.toolbar, null);
>     homeActionbar.setCustomView(v);
>     homeActionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
>
>     //Set Custom ToolBar Objects...
>     //MainToolBar Menu Image Object...
>     mainToolbarMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_menu);
>     mainToolbarMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             if (homeDLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
>                 homeDLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>             else homeDLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>         }
>     });
>
>     //Set Custom Home Navigation Drawer...
>     draweritems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_titles);
>     drawerItems = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(draweritems));
>     drawerCustomListAdapter = new DrawerCustomListAdapter(this, draweritems);
>     homeDrawerListView.setAdapter(drawerCustomListAdapter);
>     // homeDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
>     //        this,R.layout.drawer_list_row,homeDrawerMenuItems));
>
>
>     // homeDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
>     //        this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,homeDrawerMenuItems));
>
>     homeDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
>             String selectedItem = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_titles)[position];
>             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "برروی " + selectedItem + "کلیک شد!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     });
>
>     FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
>     fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
>                     .setAction("Action", null).show();
>         }
>     });
>
> } }
> ```
>
> package ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.Core.adapter;
>
> ```
>     import android.content.Context;
>
>     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>     import android.view.View;
>     import android.view.ViewGroup;
>     import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
>     import android.widget.ImageView;
>     import android.widget.TextView;
>
>
>     import java.util.ArrayList;
>     import java.util.List;
>
>     import ir.safarbazha.safarbazha.R;
> ```
>
> public class DrawerCustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
>
> ```
> public Context context;
> public List<String> drawerItems;
> private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
>
> public void DrawerCustomListAdapter(
>         Context context, List<String> drawerItems
> ) {
>     this.context = context;
>     this.drawerItems = drawerItems;
>     inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     return drawerItems.size();
> }
>
> @Override
> public Object getItem(int position) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     return drawerItems.get(position);
> }
>
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     return position;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     View vi = convertView;
>     if (vi == null)
>         vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_row, null);
>     TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_title);
>     title.setText(drawerItems.get(position));
>     ImageView icon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_icon);
>     icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_left);
>     return vi;
> }
>
> /*
>
> public Object getItem(int position) {
>     return position;
> }
>
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>     return position;
> }
>
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     View vi=convertView;
>     if(convertView==null)
>         vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_row, null);
>
>     TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_title); // title
>     ImageView icon=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_lv_icon); // thumb image
>
>     // Setting all values in listview
>     title.setText(R.string.app_name);
>     icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_account_circle);
>     return vi;
> }
> */ }
> ```

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor to create code blocks, not the quotation button